# How to apply horizontal space between absolute positioned elements

Tags: html, css

I created a set of four `div` tags with a `background-color` of yellow, and specified a `width` and `height` and then I set its position to `absolute` and `bottom` to `0px` as shown in the code below :

```css
 #votingmeter {
    width:25em;
    height:20em;
    background-color:black;
}

 .voteindex {
    width:2em;
    height:8em;
    background-color:yellow;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin:2em;
}
```

```html
<div id="votingmeter"> 

 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>

</div>
```

(Please see `.votingindex`)

But the problem is that the `.votingindex` elements are overlapping. I wish to apply some space between each `div` elements.

Can anyone please suggest me a way to do it?

Also, I want the yellow divs(.voteindex) to stay within the black div (`#votingmeter`).

Comment: you need to you use `nth-child` of css. Check  can check it my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap .voteindex divs in div with position absolute.

```css
 #votingmeter {  width:25em;height:20em;background-color:black; position: relative; }

 .voteindex { width:2em;height:8em;
             background-color:yellow;float:left;
             margin:2em;}
 .bottom {
   position:absolute;bottom:0;
 }
```

```html
<body>

<div id="votingmeter"> 
 <div class="bottom">
  <div class="voteindex"></div>
  <div class="voteindex"></div>
  <div class="voteindex"></div>
  <div class="voteindex"></div>
 </div>

</div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: This worked! Great help.Thanks a lot brother!I I wonder how your suggestion went unnoticed for so long!

Answer (score 2):

`position:absolute;` is the one that that causes the elements to overlap. If I remove that part, the elements are divided evenly over the area, so it seems you have done your calculations well.

```css
 #votingmeter {  width:25em;height:20em;background-color:black; }

 .voteindex { width:2em;height:8em;
             background-color:yellow;float:left;
             bottom:0;margin:2em;}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="votingmeter"> 

 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>

</div>
  
</body>
```

With `position: absolute`, you position your elements within the nearest parent that also has position: absolute or relative. In your case now of those is specified, so the body is used. With that, you can give each of your yellow blocks a `top` and `left`, but since you didn't do that, they all turn out to be in the same spot. In this case, I think removing position is more elegant than specifying coordinates per item.

An alternative solution if you want to position the elements at the bottom. You can make the yellow blocks `inline-block`. This will make them behave like images: they will be included in the flow of the text. You can then make the line-height of the container very high, so the black box actually becomes a single line of 'text'.

```css
#votingmeter {  width:25em;line-height:20em;background-color:black; }

 .voteindex {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: bottom;
   width:2em;
   height:8em;
   background-color:yellow;
   bottom:0;
   margin:2em;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="votingmeter"> 

 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>
 <div class="voteindex"></div>

</div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: It's working fine regarding the spacing between elements.Great! But again I also need to specify the divs in such a way that when I increase the height of the yellow divs, it must increase upwards.Can you suggest me a way to do that too?

Comment: You mean they should start at the bottom and rise upwards, within the black area?

Comment: Exactly.Know any method?

Comment: I was trying that, but I have to go. I've pasted the suggestion at the bottom of the answer, but I don't have time to explain now, sorry.

Comment: It's ok.Please answer when you get time.Thank you for your great help.

Comment: You accepted Kepi's solution, which is fine, because I think that solution is actually better. Nevertheless, I've added a little explanation to my alternative solution, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `absolute` positioning? Just float the `div` elements and use *px* instead of *em*, for the container and for the inner elements. Plus, inner elements must have set a margin to left to have some space.

```
#votingmeter { 
   width:400px;
   height:20em;
   background-color:black;
}

.voteindex { 
   width:50px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:red;
   float:left; 
   margin-left:10px
}
```

Here is a [working code](http://jsbin.com/qamilesaqe/1/edit?html,css,output) to test.

Comment: The reason why I used the position absolute is because I want the yellow divs' height to increase upwards when I give a higher value to the height property.My intention is to create an animation in which the divs' height will go up and down as in a graph.

Comment: Ah, ok. Then, i think @GolezTrol user suggest the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need like following. It's using pure css.

```css
#votingmeter {
    height: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    
    position: relative;
    background-color:black;
        width:100%;
}

.voteindex {
   background: yellow;
    bottom: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;      
    animation: sound 0ms -800ms linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes sound {
    0% {
       opacity: .35;
        height: 30px; 
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;       
        height: 99px;        
    }
}

.voteindex:nth-child(1)  { left: 1px; animation-duration: 474ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(2)  { left: 12px; animation-duration: 433ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(3)  { left: 25px; animation-duration: 407ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(4)  { left: 37px; animation-duration: 458ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(5)  { left: 49px; animation-duration: 400ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(6)  { left: 52px; animation-duration: 427ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(7)  { left: 65px; animation-duration: 441ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(8)  { left: 77px; animation-duration: 419ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(9)  { left: 89px; animation-duration: 487ms; }
.voteindex:nth-child(10) { left: 102px; animation-duration: 442ms; }​
```

```html
<div id="votingmeter">
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
    <div class="voteindex"></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

You can check [Fiddle Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/w67y288f/4/)

Comment: It's not moving bro.Why is it so?Please recheck your fiddle.